# Eclipse Juno - Subversive SVN - Connection Timeout - Sorry, this connection is closed

Tags: eclipse, subversive, eclipse-juno, svnkit

I've got the following problem: Since my update from Eclipse `Helios` to `Juno` my `SVN` seems to close the connection after a while to the server and can't reconnect.

I get the following:

> Sorry, this connection is closed.

My server uses `SVN v1.6.12`. I'm using Eclipse `Juno` v4.2 and `Subversive SVN` and the `SVNKit 1.3.8 Implementation (Optional)`. The newer SVNKit Connector with v1.7.5.v1 doesn't work at all.

Any ideas why this happens or how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you try adding a Native JavaHL connector? (1.6+ or 1.7+) and see if the issue persists? A bit like in http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2012/09/subversive-fix-commit-operation-failed.html

Comment: i installed it. now i have to wait :)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I have the same problem with Indigo

Comment: Not entirely sure, but it seems that a IPv6 connection causes this error for me. I have no problems what so ever via IPv4 internet.

Comment: Well, I used IPv4 for sure... but thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue (  svn: Sorry, this connection is closed.) that SVN (in eclipse) close the connection after a while and sometimes I have to restart the eclipse to get it going again.

I changed the SVN Connector under Window > Preferences > Team > SVN > SVN Connector and it seems to work fine upto now.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the comment, the article "[[SOLVED] Fixing Subversive Commit Operation Failed Error in Eclipse!](http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2012/09/subversive-fix-commit-operation-failed.html)" describes the various connectors you could try, when you see the following error:

[image: svn error]

Amongst the commectors, you have one you didn't mention: SVN JavaHL

[image: SVN Connectors]

Adding a JavaHL (1.6 or 1.7) connector might solve the issue.

Comment: I Have JavaHL 1.8.11 and still I have problems with connection timeout